# setup janus in ubuntu 18.04 lts issue in installing libnice

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, janus

i am following this tutorial to setup janus on my machine
on step 2

install_libnice.sh

```
#!/bin/bash


# install_libnice.sh
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libnice/libnice.git
cd libnice
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr
make && sudo make install
```

and executing this command

```
bash install_libnice.sh
```

gives

```
Cloning into 'libnice'...
warning: redirecting to https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libnice/libnice.git/
remote: Enumerating objects: 15336, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (15336/15336), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4011/4011), done.
remote: Total 15336 (delta 11795), reused 14714 (delta 11278), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (15336/15336), 2.77 MiB | 429.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (11795/11795), done.
install_libnice.sh: line 6: ./autogen.sh: No such file or directory
install_libnice.sh: line 7: ./configure: No such file or directory
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

how can i resolve this issue in ubuntu ?

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libnice/libnice

libnice use now meson builder